# Binding doesn't subscribe to PropertyChangedHandler

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Alright so I've been on this for ages now and can't see why it doesn't work.

I Have a binding from my UserControl label onto a property in the class `cell`. This class implements the interface `INotifyPropertyChanged`. There everytime the set method is called it will call `OnPropertyChanged("value)`which is expected to update the label that it's binded to. However this is not the case.

I did some research on stack to clarify some of the problems i've checked:

I do have my datacontext set since I use mvvm light it is set to the viewmodel locator.

this property is outside of the viewmodel but it's suppose to be in order to not make it more expandable towards other sizes of sudoku.

**Edit:** The Property changed is fired however the handler is always null I suspect it's not being subscribed to, hence the title.

**Edit 2** The code is Sudoku game which is basically a grid of 3x3 with grids of 3x3 The hiarchy here would be Outtergrid has innergrids and innergrids have cells I thought it would be better not to include these codes since they are basically the same.

Snipit of the datacontext declared MainWindow.Window:

```
<Window x:Class="SudokuWPF.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SudokuWPF"
    DataContext="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"
    Title="SudokuWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
```

here is the code of the `Cell` class

```
public class Cell : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int _value;



    public int Value
    {
        get { return _value; }
        set
        {
            _value = value;
            //Content = _value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Value");
        } 
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

And the binding in the usercontrol

```
<UserControl x:Class="SudokuWPF.UserControlSudoku"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:LocalControl="clr-namespace:SudokuWPF"
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="d"
         HorizontalAlignment ="Stretch"
         HorizontalContentAlignment ="Stretch"
         VerticalAlignment ="Stretch"
         VerticalContentAlignment ="Stretch"
         Foreground="White"
         Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=ActualHeight}">
<UserControl.Resources>

    <LocalControl:Cell x:Key="Cell"></LocalControl:Cell>
    <LocalControl:Innergrid x:Key="Innergrid"></LocalControl:Innergrid>
    <LocalControl:OuterGrid x:Key="OuterGrid"></LocalControl:OuterGrid>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="CellTemplate">
        <Border x:Name="Border" BorderBrush="AliceBlue" BorderThickness="1">
            <Label Content="{Binding Source={StaticResource Cell}, Path=Value, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></Label>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you're accessing the same instance ?

Comment: I think so otherwise the OnPropertyChanged couldn't have been fired would it? it's ignoring the PropertyChangedEventArgs since there is no handler and I've read that it would be bad practise to not have this checked of hence the if around it

Comment: *“this property is outside of the viewmodel but it's suppose to be”* – Why?

Comment: Sorry #Ed Plunkett I forgot to add the code snippit to that i'll also explain my hiarchy better to where this cell comes from

Comment: @poke I want the UI to update per cell or innergrid so that whenever one cell changes I do not have to update the whole UI. This so it's easily expandable.

Comment: If you have a data context, why are you referring to a StaticResource in your binding?

Comment: @MikaelNitell because this datacontext is set in the Mainwindow.window. Side question: Is it possible to have another datacontext in the usercontrol?

Comment: May not know enough about your code, but why is OnPropertyChanged virtual?  Who implements it?

Answer (score 0):

Alright so after wrongfully eliminating the datacontext out of the problem it turned out this was the core of the problem. I now binded the datacontext to my outer grid object like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="SudokuWPF.UserControlSudoku"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="d"
         HorizontalAlignment ="Stretch"
         HorizontalContentAlignment ="Stretch"
         VerticalAlignment ="Stretch"
         VerticalContentAlignment ="Stretch"
         Foreground="White"
         Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=ActualHeight}"
         DataContext="{Binding Source=OuterGrid}"
        >


public OuterGrid outerGrid = new OuterGrid();
    public UserControlSudoku()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MainList.DataContext = outerGrid;
    }
```